# Setting a query to look for either field value

Tags: php, sql

The query below will search users with the name and like and which email_activated = 1. Now I want the query to search for name like fname email_activated = 1 OR email_activated= 0. So if the query finds a name similar to Smith Joseph with email_activated = 1 OR email_activated= 0, then display, no matter if the email_activated field value is 1 or 0. Display both if there is two different names with that fields with value 1 and 0 two.

How can I achieve that query?

```
 $queryString = "WHERE name LIKE '%$fname%' AND email_activated='1'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$queryString = "WHERE name LIKE '%$fname%' AND (email_activated='1' OR email_activated='0')";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in` for that ;)

```
WHERE name LIKE '%$fname%' and email_activated in ('0','1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using mysql:

```
 $queryString = "WHERE name LIKE '%$fname%' AND email_activated in ('0','1')";
```

But you should consider if `email_activated` is a column that accepts null values, or contains other possible values. In these cases the rows that have null or other values won't appear in your select with the where clause above.

Comment: What about Null values ? If the column doesn't accept null values, then you're better off removing the column from the where clause, as in the other answer in this page.

Comment: really, What do you mean by null values? other than 0 and 1?

Comment: it is true what you said Nilocl

Comment: Every column can be defined to allow a special value, called the `null` value. ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL) ). In MySql you can check in the table definition how its columns are setup, with the command `describe TABLENAME;`, TABLENAME being the name of the table in your database. What is your database ? Mysql ? Sql Server ?

Comment: Sorry, seems like the link broke because of the parenthesis. Just copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing `email_activated` field have only two values `'1' or '0'`. If that is the case you can simply ignore that field. Then the query string will look simply following

```
$queryString = "WHERE name LIKE '%$fname%'";
```